# Why do African-Americans not support the GOP?

Tags: united-states, republican-party, democratic-party

I am a new political enthusiast.

Recently I was studying the voting tendencies of the American ethnic group and found that most African Americans support the Democratic Party.

But one thing I noticed was that the Republican Party liberated African Americans through the Civil War, and then under the influence of the Roosevelt New Deal, African Americans began to support the Democratic Party.

I am actually very curious as to why many Republican members of Congress voted against the Civil Rights Act in 1964? Isn't this contrary to the spirit of emancipation of slaves by those Republican ancestors? (I understand it as one of the reasons African-Americans still support Democrats so far.)

Comment: Re: "the American ethnic group" I guess you meant "groups"? As for the realignment see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_strategy

Comment: @Fizz Yes, I am glad to hope you can edit this question if you think it is needed

Answer (score 1):

## A lot of time has passed

The american civil war was in the 1860s, 100 years before the civil rights act, with plenty of time for opinions and members to change.

Comment: Well, the civil rights act had more support from Republicans than Democrats, so it's not just the passage of time since the civil war.